# clarification about powershell foreach variable

Tags: powershell, foreach

Heres my code, it works but I can't understand why you need $line inside the loop

```
foreach($line in $Array) 
{ 
  Add-Content "$HOME\filename.txt" $line
}
```

I want to understand but my teacher is not being very cooperative

Comment: Let's put it another a way: what do you think should be written in the file if there wasn't the `$line` variable? Where would that data come from? What would be its content?

Comment: Need to change the teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you had written the following:

```
foreach($line in $Array)
{
    Add-Content "$HOME\filename.txt" "Hello, world"
}
```

What would be written out to the file?  The answer is that the same string,  "Hello, world"  would have been written out, over and over again, until there weren't any more items in the array.  Well, that's dumb.  So,  if you want the output on each line to reflect the aprt of the array that is current,  you have to use $line as the parameter for what you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your $Array is made of many lines, is this more clear ?

```
foreach($line in $lineS) 
{ 
  Add-Content "$HOME\filename.txt" $line
}
```